# Cannot Connect to asterisk server errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 5038

Tags: node.js

This is the error when i run the script

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5038
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 5038
}

i tried connecting to the server using AMI and asterisk-ami-client and a code that i got from github to test. I also checked the manager.conf for the credentials and permission. This is my first time posting and I am new to asterisk. Anything will help, Thank you

This is the code

const AmiClient = require('asterisk-ami-client');
let client = new AmiClient();

client.connect('user', 'secret', { host: 'localhost', port: 5038 })
.then(() => {
client
.on('connect', () => console.log('connect'))
.on('event', event => console.log(event))
.on('data', chunk => console.log(chunk))
.on('response', response => console.log(response))
.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnect'))
.on('reconnection', () => console.log('reconnection'))
.on('internalError', error => console.log(error))
.action({
Action: 'Ping'
});

```
    setTimeout(() => {
        client.disconnect();
    }, 5000);

})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```